# Finite Dimensional Representation of Lie Algebra.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products

Let $V, W, U$ be finite dimensional representations of a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Show that $\hom(V \otimes W, U) \cong \hom (V, U \otimes W^*)$.

I think I have to use the enveloping algebra of the lie algebra here but I can't find a natural isomorphism. I have tried in some simple finite cases but they aren't very illuminating. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you first show $\operatorname{hom}(W,U) \cong U \otimes W^*$?  Then, given $f \colon V \otimes W \to U$, you can set $\lambda(f)(v)$ to be the map that takes $w \in U$ to $f(v \otimes w)$.